# Can I use extensions in Selenium with Chromedriver with headless mode?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver, headless

```
def __get_chromedriver(self, use_proxy=False, user_agent=None):
    CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = os.environ.get('CHROMEDRIVER_PATH', '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
    GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN', '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable')

    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.binary_location = GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-web-security')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://proxy-server.scraperapi.com:8001')
    chrome_options.add_argument("ignore-certificate-errors")

    chrome_options.add_argument('headless')

    if use_proxy:
        pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'

        with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
            zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
            zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)
        chrome_options.add_extension(pluginfile)
    if user_agent:
        chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=%s' % user_agent)


    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH,
        chrome_options=chrome_options)
    return driver
```

When I try to build the driver I got this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: failed to wait for extension background page to load: chrome-extension://icbdedkkdagkbepbnchafmojcchonbmj/_generated_background_page.html
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://icbdedkkdagkbepbnchafmojcchonbmj/_generated_background_page.html
```

But if I comment `chrome_options.add_argument('headless')` it works fine.

Unfortunately I want to use Chromedriver with headless mode, some ideas?

Comment: No, https://crbug.com/706008.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this feature is not implemented yet:

[Google Discussion about it](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OeUik1MZb1qSQ_Dnf1kIYcyCgLYRZHg1GlZo06bsKx4/edit#)

[Chromium bugs official discussion](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008#c5)